# Synonymize individual scripting tags with one generic scripting tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment we have individual tags for [photoshop-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-scripting), [illustrator-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illustrator-scripting), [acrobat-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acrobat-scripting), [indesign-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indesign-scripting) etc. *and* individual tags (on most all of questions that use those tags) for [adobe-photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop), [adobe-illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator), [adobe-acrobat](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-acrobat), [adobe-indesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign), etc. This is redundant. If someone really likes scripting, they'd have to follow each of the different scripting tags.

Why not have one singular [scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) tag and make the others synonyms of it? That way a question will, for example, have only [adobe-photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) and [scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) on it?

P.S. Right now the [scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) tag is a synonym for just [photoshop-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-scripting) which seems incorrect to me.

P.P.S. The [automation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation) tag might should be a synonym of [scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) as well?

P.P.P.S The difference between [script](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) and [scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) should probably be clarified (if there is a significant enough difference).

Comment: There is a lot going on in there, should probably break this up into multiple posts, so that each *issue* can be addressed and handled properly.

Comment: Is it a mere coincidence that you only list Adobe software here?

Comment: @usr2564301 there's no [inkscape-scripting] or [gimp-scripting] tags that I know of, so that might be the reason

Answer (score 2):

I don't think [automation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation) is a synonym for [scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting).

Although scripting will fall under the category of automation, I generally think that the [automation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation) applies specifically to batch processing (which may be a better synonym).

Comment: Automation includes batch processing, scripting, Photoshop Actions, and can also be used for questions on workflow improvement in general. So I don't think we should merge it with batch processing, which is specific to processing several files.

Comment: @Luciano I agree with that.